# How can I deploy a Cloud Function Gen1 and Gen2 function from the same codebase?

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a Gen1 and Gen2 Cloud Function from the same codebase. (Because firebase auth events are only supported in Gen1).

The deploy works fine if I deploy 1 or the other, but if I add the 2 together, an error is throw: `Function failed to start: no matching function found with name: "MyGen1Func"`

This is my `functions.go` root file:

```golang
package functions

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/functions"
)

type Event struct {
  // ...
}

func MyGen1Func(ctx context.Context, data Event) error {
  // ...
}

func init() {
    functions.HTTP("MyGen2Func", func (w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
      // ...
    })

}
```

And this is (mostly) how they're deployed in cloudbuild:

```
gcloud functions deploy MyGen1Func \
     --runtime go120 \
     --source ./ \
     --trigger-event providers/firebase.auth/eventTypes/user.create \
     --entry-point MyGen1Func


gcloud functions deploy MyGen2Func \
     --gen2 \
     --runtime go120 \
     --source ./ \
     --trigger-http \
     --allow-unauthenticated
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you were still working in bash, you could use flags-files for your cloud functions that contain all of the flags necessary for that specific function. The bash version would be `gcloud functions deploy MyGen2Func --flags-file=<FLAGS_FILE>`. Here's more info on flags-files: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/flags-file; I don't write Golang, but here's an example of a Golang script that parses a flags-file: https://github.com/google/trillian/blob/master/cmd/trillian_log_server/main.go

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can just export both gen1 and gen2 functions from the root package and add an environment variable when deploying the gen2 function to mark the entry point:

`--set-env-vars FUNCTION_TARGET=MyGen2Func`

```golang
package functions

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
)

func MyGen1Func(ctx context.Context, data Event) error {
  // ...
}

func MyGen2Func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  // ...
}
```